# Displaying content of multiple .txt files with the same filename in all subdirectories

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have multiple files with the same filename under various subdirectories, for example:

```
c:\kjhsd\client.txt
c:\ekjjs\client.txt
c:\oiwnk\client.txt
```

I do not know the middle part of the path represented by random letters above, but the filename is always consistent.

I need a way to use this command: `type client.txt` (or) `more client.txt` but to display the content of all text files with the filename "client.txt" under any directory at the same time.

So if:

`c:\kjhsd\client.txt` contained: `hello`

`c:\ekjjs\client.txt` contained: `helloworld`

`c:\oiwnk\client.txt` contained: `helloagain`

After running the single command, I would see:

```
hello
helloworld
helloagain
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from `cmd.exe`:

```
@for /r c:\ %a in ("client.txt") do @type "%~a"2>nul
```

From a `Batch-File`:

```
@for /r c:\ %%a in ("client.txt") do @type "%%~a"2>nul
```

**Edit:** as per the newline requirement:

```
@echo off
Pushd "c:\somedir"
for /f %%a in ('dir /b /s /a-d ^| find /i "client.txt"') do (
    type "%%~a"2>nul
    echo(
)
Popd
```

or if you want to see which file had what text:

```
@echo off
Pushd "c:\somedir"
for /f %%a in ('dir /b /s /a-d ^| find /i "client.txt"') do (
    echo content: "%%~a"
    type "%%~a"2>nul
    echo(
)
Popd
```

Comment: Thanks so much Gerhard! This is working, but it is not putting a breakline between text files. So I'm getting the equivalent of:

hellohelloworldagain

Comment: a break line? So you want a newline each time after the previous files results ended?

Comment: Thanks Gerhard! This batch needs to be run from the parent directory right? Is there anywhere to specify a different parent root so that the batch file can be run from elseware? Thanks again!

Comment: I facepalmed as soon as I saw your update. I should have known to simply use a pushd! Sorry! Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest approach is to use a [`for /D` loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html) to find the different directories, and to let [`find /V ""`](https://ss64.com/nt/find.html) return the contents of the files, because then a line-break is automatically appended to every file in case there is none in the file itself (opposed to [`type`](https://ss64.com/nt/type.html)).

In Command Prompt do this:

```cmd
@for /D %I in ("D:\some\root\*") do @(< "%~I\client.txt" find /V "") 2> nul
```

In a batch file do this:

```cmd
@for /D %%I in ("D:\some\root\*") do @(< "%%~I\client.txt" find /V "") 2> nul
```

The [`2> nul`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) portion suppresses eerror messages if a directory does not contain a file called `client.txt`.

Comment: aschipfl, I have a feeling that this isn't looking for 'any directory', i.e. fully recursive

Comment: Yes @Compo, this behaviour is intentional, because of the introduction and the sample dirs./files in the question...

Comment: Yes, those samples do suggest one level only. Thanks for clarifying.